# Key board shortcut to compile a selected file in VS IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008-sp1

Is there any keyboard short cut to compile selected file in C++ project in VS 2008?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mine it's Ctrl+F7

Comment: Annoying that I couldn't just enter "Ctrl+F7" as my answer, had to buffer it out to pass the minimum characters limit :/

Answer (score 1):

You can customize what you need via: Tools -> options -> keyboard and search for the compile command with 'compile' keyboard.

I, for example, create Ctrl-B, Ctrl-B shortcut that builds a C# project, which there is no default one binding this command.